# How to fetch data from a table from the result of same table in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Hibernate with spring Rest and i am fetching data from a table. There are two columns in my table username and profession. I created a method in which i am passing a username and getting a profession corresponding to username now i want to search by profession which i got and want to get all usernames who have that profession.

I have fetched profession using a username but i am unable to fetch usernames who have that profession so please suggest me the way to do this.

Here is my Entity class **Profession.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profession")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Profession implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="profession")
private String profession;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;


//Getters and setters

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}

}
```

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Profession> getProfessionById(String uname) throws Exception {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  String queryString = "from Profession where username = :uname";
  Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
  query.setString("uname", uname);
  //List<Profession> queryResult = (List<Profession>) query.uniqueResult();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  return query.list();
```

}

Please help me . Thanx in advance

Comment: Whats exactly the name of your db table?
Profession or user_profession?

Comment: user_profession   ..Profession is enitity class name

Comment: and it has columns named id, username and profession

Comment: Are you getting Exception? Or Simple data not fetched?

Comment: @nad What exception you are facing ?

Comment: i have fetched a profession of a single user by passing a username but now i want to fetch the usernames of that profession which i have fetched

Comment: i am not getting exception.. actually i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added this code

```
 String queryString = "from Profession where username = :uname";
 Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
 query.setString("uname", uname);
```

But missing

```
  List<Profession> professionList = query.list();
   for(Profession profession: professionList ){
     System.out.println("Get What you need Like"+profession.getUsername());
    }
```

Comment: actually i am getting profession of a user  but now i want to use that profession to fetch another results which have that profession

Comment: i am not getting any exception bt i dont know how can i get results of that profession

Comment: You have to use `for` or `Iterator` loop check updated answer

Comment: sory i cant because i dont have 15 reputations. please +1 my question