# Getting only last record in Hibernate but i want all records

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I am using Hibernate with Spring Rest. I have two tables in my database named user_table and user_profession. user_table contains user info and primary key is id. user_profession contains the profession of user with u_id foreign key. The working of project is that i pass u_id into user_profession and get a profession of user now from that profession i fetch all the u_id from user_profession table which have that profession . And now i got many u_id from user_profession and now i map user_profession with user_table using @OneToOne mapping and got the user info corresponding to that u_id.

It is working fine if a single u_id has single profession in user_profession but if a u_id has multiple entries with multiple professions then i am getting only last profession result while i want that if i pass a u_id into user_profession table and if that u_id has two entries with two professions then it could search u_id for both the professions but it is fetching only second profession u_ids.

Here is My Entity classes for both tables. First is **Profession.java** for user_profession table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profession")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Profession implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="profession")
private String profession;

@Column(name="u_id")
private String u_id;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "u_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private User user;


//Getters and setters


public User getUser() {
    return user;
}


public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public String getU_id() {
    return u_id;
}

public void setU_id(String u_id) {
    this.u_id = u_id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}

}
```

Here is **User.java** for user_table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;


public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}


}
```

Here is my **DAO** class

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Profession> getProfessionById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
      session.beginTransaction();
      String queryString = "from Profession where u_id = :id";
      Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
      query.setLong("id", id);

      List<Profession> professionList = query.list();

        String queryString1 = "from Profession where profession = :pro";
          Query query1 = null;

          for(Profession professionList1 : professionList){
            query1=session.createQuery(queryString1);
            query1.setString("pro", professionList1.getProfession());

          }

      session.flush();
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      return query1.list();
}
```

Comment: You're recreating the query in the loop and thus end up with only the last one. Call `query1.list()` inside the loop and collect the results yourself or - yet better if possible - change your query to get all entities in one query.

Comment: One simple question on your queries: why do you load the `Profession` by (user?) id and then load it again? Seems to make no sense. - Btw, please be more specific in naming your variables and methods. This would make reading your code much easier, i.e. I assume the parameter `id` actually means the user id and not the profession id.

Comment: Yet another observation: your user ids are of type `long` while profession's `u_id` is of type `String` but it seems to refer to the same column. While this _might_ not cause problems (I don't do that myself) it seems at least highly unusual and I'd not rule out any subtle errors due to this.

Comment: u can try with **IN Operator** to get all entities in one query.Current approach is not good at all.

Comment: Asking the same question 3 times in 2 days isn't going to help you getting an answer sooner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918205/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-table-from-the-result-of-same-table-in-hibernate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937320/how-to-return-all-records-when-join-two-tables-using-foreign-key-in-hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with just one query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Profession> getProfessionById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    // Why would you need a transaction?
    // session.beginTransaction();
    String queryString = "SELECT p2 FROM Profession p1, Profession p2 WHERE p1.u_id=:id AND p2.profession=p1.profession";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setLong("id", id);

    return query.list();
}
```

If you want to get all users who have the same profession(s) as the specified user instead of all Profession entries you have to change your code to something like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getUsersWithSameProfessionsById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM Profession p1, Profession p2 JOIN p2.user u WHERE p1.u_id=:id AND p2.profession=p1.profession";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setLong("id", id);

    return query.list();
}
```

(I know, "DISTINCT", bad style - you could also use a "GROUP BY".)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response...your code is working fine but i am getting repitition of u_ids like if there is a u_id already exist in one profession then it is also showing for another profession... but i want a single u_id only once

Comment: @nad: To clarify that: even if the specified User has more than one profession you do only want one Profession per User? If so, which Profession to choose?

Comment: CEO would be my first choice... :D

Comment: @rostbot No no... i want all professions.. i am saying if any user has two professions and we search for all the u_ids which are having these two professions then if any other user has both the professions then it is coming for both professions in search result..so there is duplicacy of u_ids. because i want a u_id only one time.

Comment: @nad: So actually your target is not to have a list of professions, but a list of users?

Comment: yes .. i want all users...see my Profession class i am using @OneToOne mapping to get users

Comment: @nad I've added a second method that immediately gives you all users in question.